# What are supported 4e campaign settings?

Tags: dnd-4e, campaign-settings

By "supported" I mean there is at least one book (or similar-level online resource) detailing the setting. Campaign settings I already know about for 4e: Nentir Vale (not well supported), Forgotten Realms, Eberron...

I'm interested in "supported" 4e settings so that I don't have to generate all the fluff. For various reasons, Eberron and FR are out for my immediate needs...

Just to give more clarity to "supported": Planescape and Greyhawk would be examples of campaign settings that don't seem to be supported (with books) for 4e, although older works exist.

I'm especially interested in whether there are any good 3rd party settings.

Comment: To close-voters: Yes, this is asking for a list, but the word "list" is not an immediate reason to close. It's asking for a complete list in one answer (which is fine), not a unbounded list of different answers (not fine). Since WotC is no longer publishing 4e campaign settings, this will not require maintenance as the correct list changes, either, since it won't be changing. It is an exemplar of a "good list" question.

Comment: Here's a +1 your trouble, AdamC. Good question!

Comment: @BESW Given how 3PP-hostile the GSL is, there aren't, and never will be, very many 3rd-party 4e settings. If this was a 3e/d20 question it'd be a massive, ever-expanding list, but that's just not the case with 4e.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [official catalog](http://wizards.com/dnd/Catalog.aspx) the following campaign settings exist for D&D 4e:

- [Points of Light](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/18250/4398), also known as Nentir Vale after the DMG sample community set in PoL (standard setting)
- Eberron
- Forgotten Realms
- Dark Sun

While a sort of mini-game, some players count Gamma World as a setting too.

You can found all these info and some 3rd party settings [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=251317)

> - Wraith Recon
> - Amethyst
> - Scarrport (one city only)
> - Kingdoms of Kalamar
> - 4e Ultramodern (does anyone know if this is a setting or just a rules set?)

Whether these settings are good or not, I cannot say.

Comment: It's also worth noting that large, significant elements of Spelljammer, Ravenloft and Planescape have been incorporated into the PoL setting.

Comment: Would highly suggest darksun, lots of fluff and flavor, interesting mechanics if you go by the books (inherent bonuses, extremely rare magic items, masterwork armors instead of magic armors, alternate rewards to pickup the magic item power slack). Its also lends itself more towards a gritty style (endurance checks for traveling without supplies) if that's what you are looking for.